# An urn contains 4 red balls and 2 white balls. Players Homer and Bart alternately take turn drawing a ball until a player selects a red ball.

Tags: probability

> An urn contains 4 red balls and 2 white balls. Players Homer and Bart alternately take turn drawing a ball until a player selects a red ball. (A drawn ball is not returned to the urn.) What is the probability that the player who selects first will win?

I thought the solving process would be by using permutations, but I can't reach a result with that. Could you please tell me what kind of process or formula should I use? thanks.

Comment: "*probability trees*" is the name of the tool as I was taught it... The more formal name might be "*multiplication principle (of probability)*".  The first person wins either because their first selection was red, or they win because their first selection was white and second person also selected white after which the only balls left available are all red and so they win.

Comment: Wow, Russian Roulette with four bullets. That's hardcore.

Comment: @MJD Ah, but see... it is a question about cartoon characters from the 90's to try to be hip and cool and grab kids interest... (/sarcasm).  I never did like how some question authors shoehorn details like this in that in no way change the flavor or affect the question in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say Homer goes first. There's a $2/3$ probability that he wins immediately by drawing a red ball. If this doesn't happen (with probability $1/3$), then the only way he still wins is if Bart draws the other remaining white ball, which happens with probability $1/5$. If Bart does draw the other white ball, then only red balls will remain at this point, so Homer is certain to win. So the overall probability that Homer wins is $P = 2/3 + (1/3)(1/5) = 11/15$.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you what is the formula behind this? For example let's say we have to find the probability that the second player wins. Do we have to do 
P = 2/3 + (1/3)(1/5) + (3/5) + (1/5) ?

Comment: For ease of notation, I'll write $Pr(R1)$ to mean "probability of Red on the 1st draw" etc. Then the more general formula would be something like $P = Pr(R1) + Pr(W1)Pr(W2|W1)\cdot(Pr(R3|W2,W1) + Pr(W3|W2,W1)Pr(W4|W3,W2,W1)\cdot(...))$, keeping in mind that $R1\cup R3\cup R5 ...$ = 1 wins. You keep extending the $()$ inwards as long as you need to. In this case, $Pr(R3|W2,W1)=1$ and $Pr(W3|W2,W1)=0$ so you do not need to go very far. However, tbth I prefer to just reason through it logically, rather than think about it always in terms of formulas - I just find this easier.

Comment: To answer your other question: if you already know $Pr(1 \text{ wins})=11/15$ then you can of course calculate $Pr(2 \text{ wins})=1-Pr(1 \text{ wins})=4/15$. If the question had asked about player 2 from the get-go, I'd reason like this: first, Homer needs to draw a white ball. With that done, Bart must draw a red ball to win, bc if he draws the other white ball, Homer wins for sure, as now there are no more white balls left. So $P = Pr(W1)Pr(R2|W1) = (1/3)(4/5) = 4/15$.